# How to create index in servral sql condition?

Tags: clickhouse

Data is like starttime, endtime, id, a, b, c, d, e, f, g...

How to create index on clickhouse, most sql is as follows:

> 1.select starttime,endtime,id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tbl1 
>   where starttime>=? and endtime<=? and id=?
>
> 2.select a,c,sum(f),avg(g) from tbl1 
>   where starttime>=? and endtime<=? 
>   group by a,c 
>   order by sum(f) desc 
>   limit 20
>
> 3.select starttime,endtime,id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tbl1 
>   where starttime>=? and endtime<=? and a=? 
>   limit 20
>
> 4.select a,c,sum(f),avg(g) from tbl1 
>   where starttime>=? and endtime<=? and a=? and c=? 
>   group by a,c 
>   order by sum(f) desc 
>   limit 20
>
> 5.select a,b,c,d,e,f,g from tbl1 
>   where starttime>=? and endtime<=? and a=? and d=? and e=? 
>   order by a,d,e 
>   limit 20

tips:
a) always have starttime, endtime

b) some SQL have an id to search small data, example 1. but others to search large data, example 2,3,4,5

Comment: Please format your question better. Putting everything in one line is not good.

Comment: Are those time ranges between starrtime and enddtime narrow (like minutes) or wide (days/weeks/month)?

Answer (score 0):

Clickhouse is a COLUMN oriented database with one Primary Key, he store each column on separate optimized "storage" which doesn't need secondary indexes

you can choose *MergeTree table engine with starttime and endtime in primary key 
every kind of MergeTree engine describe here https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/table_engines/mergetree/

All your queries will run as fast as possible